# Can't take screenshot using selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, web-testing

Just met a strange problem while running selenium to take the screenshot of web page, below is part of my code:

```
url = "http://acme.com/licensemaker/licensemaker.cgi?state=California"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.maximize_window()
elem = driver.get(url)
elem = \
driver.find_element_by_xpath
('/html/body/form/center/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[2]')
elem.send_keys(comb)
driver.find_element_by_xpath
('/html/body/form/center/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[3]').click()
driver.save_screenshot('../screenshots/1.png')
print('ok')
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center[1]/div/a/img')
location = img.location
size = img.size
print(size)
```

I try both PhantomJS and Safari driver neither can they save the screenshot, but I can get the output of both 'ok' and the value of 'location'.
I don't understand why I can't save the screenshot.

Saving the file via absolute path failed but only name worked. I use the same version of Selenium last year it worked with relative path, what happened?

The result of `save_screenshot()` is `True`.

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.5
Interpreter: 2.7.12(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7)
plus, I'm using Pyenv, and my Pyenv global is 'system'.

Comment: [According to the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot) you have to use full paths: "Returns False if there is any IOError, else returns True. Use full paths in your filename. [...] Usage: driver.save_screenshot(‘/Screenshots/foo.png’)"

Comment: just try without path and only name, and check if the screenshots are getting saved in the program directory or not

Comment: @try-catch-finally  absolute path failed but only name worked. I use the same version of selenium last year it worked with relative path, what happened?

Comment: @Exprator only name is good.Thx.

Comment: [Per source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.4.0/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L832) I can't see why relative paths should not work. I tested it and it works (on Linux). Please edit your post and add the platform you're running the tests on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the fact that, while invoking `save_screenshot()` you have to mention the full path you wish to save your screenshot to. This should end with a `.png` extension. As per your case, you may consider to create a directory by the name **"screenshots"** within your project space through your *IDE* or *manually*. In your code mention the path as:

```
driver.save_screenshot('/screenshots/123.png')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't save the screenshot, however, when I use only name it worked, odd.

Comment: @ShubhamJain updated the Answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB - I have found another way and posted it as an answer. I will try your solution also .. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function for relative path as absolute path is not a good idea to add in script

**Import**

```
import sys, os
```

Use code as below :

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
screenshotpath = os.path.join(os.path.sep, ROOT_DIR,'Screenshots'+ os.sep)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(screenshotpath+"testPngFunction.png")
```

make sure you create folder where .py file is present.

os.path.join also prevent you to run your script in cross platform like : unix and windows. It will generate path seprator as per OS in runtime. It is similer like **File.separtor** in java

Comment: "make sure you create folder where .py file is present." this was keypoint for my problem.